# PL/SQL - Nested if else if syntax

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-loops

I'm developing a trigger in PL/SQL.

It has this building structure:

```
if a = 1 then
    if b = 1 then
        (some code here);
    else if b=2 then
        (some code here);
    else if b=3 then
        (some code here);
    else b=4
        (some code here);
    end if;
else if a=2 then
    if b=1 then
        (some code here);
    else if b=2 then
        (some code here);
    else if b=3 then
        (some code here);
    else b=4
        (some code here);
    end if;
else
    if b=1 then
        (some code here);
    else if b=2 then
        (some code here);
    else if b=3 then
        (some code here);
    else b=4
        (some code here);
    end if;
end if;
```

However, it seems like the last else statement(a=3) is not well defined, cause the compiler says to me that expects a " ( "

Can i have a help in here?
Thank you all

Comment: the issue stems from `else if` which should be `elsif`. Need to be fixed for every occurence within your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you probably meant to say `ELSIF`, not `ELSE IF` (not only at the last place you mentioned, but *everywhere*).

Something like this:

```
if a = 1 then
    if b = 1 then
        (some code here);
    elsif b=2 then
        (some code here);
    elsif b=3 then
        (some code here);
    elsif b=4
        (some code here);
    end if;
elsif a=2 then
    if b=1 then ...
```

Comment: Somehow solved that error, however gives me an error at the `end trigger` clause, expecting semicolon, parenthesis, full stop...

If i add another `end if` at the end, the error...poof, gone, but i don't think that makes sense, what does that `end if` "closes"?

Comment: Can't tell, unless you post code you currently have.

Comment: solve me the error, so this question has to be marked as solved, thank you

Comment: I'm glad you made it work, you're welcome.